# How to force desktop view of a website onto a mobile device

Tags: html, css

I'm building a personal project website. I want to make it so that all devices (including mobile) view the desktop version of the website. Is there a simple way to do this with just HTML and/or CSS? I have seen other questions on here asking the same thing, but none of the responses worked for me.

Comment: What are you using to build the website? Is there some framework or service you're trying to use? A page of HTML and CSS should appear the same on all supported browsers, so it is usually up to some other part of your project that would serve different pages to mobile or desktop.

Comment: What didn't work? Can you post code of what you tried

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Mobile/ is the standard. Using CSS to adapt your html page to phone / iPad etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Asign your widths and heights as percentages for example `width: 50%` so that it will not have a fixed value.
If you want a navbar, you would probably use flex-box.
Here a good tutorial on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwWHL3RyQgk